# change the color of a button with a css sheet and keep the glow

Tags: css, javafx

I want to change the color of a button (javafx) to white with a css sheet. I already try with : `-fx-background-color : #FFFFFF` but I loose the glow of the button and I can't put it back with : `-fx-focus-color: #039ED3; -fx-faint-focus-color: #039ED322;`

And if I change the color with `-fx-color: #FFFFFF`, the color of the button is not white but grey...

Here, two pictures of the two situations: [Button with glow but grey](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LxVZ.png)

[Button without glow but white](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QUqS.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `-fx-body-color`.

You may want to choose different colors for hovered and armed buttons from a css stylesheet.

```css
.button {
    -fx-body-color: white;
}

.button:armed:hover {
    -fx-body-color: #CCCCCC;
}

.button:hover {
    -fx-body-color: #DDDDDD;
}
```